# Python, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming, and programming / computations in general.One of the first exercise in a book I got says to make a program that asks for 10 numbers then gives the largest odd number. I am only using what I know, I thought about using a list but I don't know much about them.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, if possible show it to me, but right now I would like to know what am I doing wrong with this code.I run the  code and when I enter 1-10 it says 3 is the largest odd number...
I also ran the code by hand and it seems to work fine, but there is an error in the code or in my logic...

```
print("Please Enter 10 digits")
num1=int(raw_input())
num2=int(raw_input())
num3=int(raw_input())
num4=int(raw_input())
num5=int(raw_input())
num6=int(raw_input())
num7=int(raw_input())
num8=int(raw_input())
num9=int(raw_input())
num10=int(raw_input())
number = 0
if num1>num2:
    if num1 %2 !=0:
        number=num1
elif num2 %2!=0:
    number=num2   

elif num3 >number:
    if num3 %2 !=0:
        number=num3
elif num4 >number:
    if num4 %2 !=0:
        number=num4
elif num5 > number:
    if num5 %2 !=0:
        number=num5
elif num6 >number:
    if num6 %2 !=0:
        number=num6
elif num7 > number:
    if num7 %2 !=0:
        number=num7
elif num8 > number:
    if num8 %2 !=0:
        number=num8
elif num9 > number:
    if num9 %2 !=0:
        number=num9
elif num10 > number:
    if num10 %2 !=0:
        number=num10
elif number == 0:
    print ("No odd numbers entred")
print(number)
raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Jerry explains, the problem is that you're using `elif` which exits at the first true condition without considering the other numbers.

I'd like to show you that you can do these things much more concisely in Python; one example would be this 4-liner:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(int(raw_input("number? ")))
print(max(filter(lambda e : e%2==1, numbers)))
```

Comment: I think the op would prefer a wordier approach that is clear algorithmically, rather than one thats as short and a cryptic as possible. Lambdas are great for experienced programmers, and mathematicians, but not really good for brand new students that are struggling with simple flow control logic.

Comment: @FrankThomas Possibly, yes, but he also asked for a simpler way to do this. I don't know anything about his background, so I will leave it up to him to say if this is simpler to him or not.

Comment: @FrankThomas BTW, I consider `lambda` mainstream since Java 8 adopted them ;-)

Comment: @FrankThomas: I disagree on the "as short and cryptic as possible" part. I think it is not cryptic at all, and I think even somebody without any knowledge of python builtins can make sense out of this snippet. Maybe the OP can act as a test person :)

Comment: @Jasper Well, to be honest, I'm quite new to python myself and have yet to understand the intricacies of `lambda` so far. Sure, I've used it a few times in answers but that was based on sample codes I found here and there.

Comment: Jerry, there is absolutely no magic to `lambda` whatsoever. In addition, Python has a crippled version of `lambda` that's even simpler than a normal function, and functions are not considered magic. Basically, `def f(x): return x+1` is the same as `f = lambda x:x+1`. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the logic is not so fine... Let's say we used 1 through 10. I'm adding some comments in the code:

```
print("Please Enter 10 digits")
num1=int(raw_input())
num2=int(raw_input())
num3=int(raw_input())
num4=int(raw_input())
num5=int(raw_input())
num6=int(raw_input())
num7=int(raw_input())
num8=int(raw_input())
num9=int(raw_input())
num10=int(raw_input())
number = 0
if num1>num2:             # "1 > 2" false
    if num1 %2 !=0:
        number=num1
elif num2 %2!=0:          # "2 % 2 != 0" false
    number=num2   

elif num3 >number:        # "3 > 0" true
    if num3 %2 !=0:       # "3 % 2 != 0" true and exit
        number=num3
elif num4 >number:
    if num4 %2 !=0:
        number=num4
elif num5 > number:
    if num5 %2 !=0:
        number=num5
elif num6 >number:
    if num6 %2 !=0:
        number=num6
elif num7 > number:
    if num7 %2 !=0:
        number=num7
elif num8 > number:
    if num8 %2 !=0:
        number=num8
elif num9 > number:
    if num9 %2 !=0:
        number=num9
elif num10 > number:
    if num10 %2 !=0:
        number=num10
elif number == 0:
    print ("No odd numbers entred")
print(number)              # Print 3
```

See now? Your code hasn't even considered the other numbers.

If you want to use a list, you might want to append each number to the same list, sort from largest to smallest and look for the first odd number:

```
print("Please Enter 10 digits")
list_numbers = []

list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))  # Append number to the list list_numbers
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))
list_numbers.append(int(raw_input()))

list_numbers.sort(reverse=True)       # Sort the numbers in reverse

for i in list_numbers:                # Loop...
    if i % 2 != 0:                    # If odd...
        print(i)                      # Print
        break                         # Exit loop
```

The above is a basic script. Usually, you can also validate the user input, and at the same time, you could put only the odd numbers in the list.

Comment: If you are using looping anyway, why not use a `for i in range(10)` loop to gather the inputs?

Comment: looping the input would save alot of repeated lines